# Tab index get increased in Jquery UI tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using Jquery UI tab plugin. 
Here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz2Mm/)

In my code I use

```
  var tabControl = $("#tabs");

    tabControl.tabs();
    tabControl.tabs({ heightStyle: "auto",
        beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {

        },
        load: function (event, ui) {

            alert(ui.panel.selector);
            if (ui.panel.selector == "#ui-tabs-1") {
                m1();
            } else if (ui.panel.selector == "#ui-tabs-2") {
                m2();
            }
        }
    });
```

When I moved to page 1st time it displays ui-tabs-1 correctly on pop up. But when I moved to some other page and come back and select the tab it shows an increased index (ui-tabs-4) and my desired method is not called. I don't know why my tab index gets increased. Your help is really appreciated.

Edit 1:

Thanks Rahul for creating the Demo. This code is part of a web application. This is related to one single page. In other pages also there are  tabs. When I first load the page alert(ui.panel.selector) shows as "#ui-tabs-1" and    when I go to other pages and come back it  shows increased id such as #ui-tabs-4". I found that in the source code (jquery.ui.tabs.js) I found following implementation.

```
var tabId = 0,
rhash = /#.*$/;

function getNextTabId() {
return ++tabId;
}
```

Seems like tabId is increased and not being reset @ . I want to reset that @ every page load. Thank you very much for concerns.

Edit 2:

I have created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/newair/Lxy5A/6/). when tabs clicked u get #ui-id-3 and #ui-id-5. In my scenario when I go back and come to the same page it displays as some increased number like #ui-id-7 for which it displayed #ui-id-3 previously.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code to reproduce the issue such the html,css or a minimal demo such as [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I have created a demo of your code and added the link to it in your question. Now please explain clearly in your question (in reference to the fiddle) exactly what is the problem and how to reproduce it ?

Comment: I have edited the question. If anything unclear let me know

Comment: Sorry ! but still not getting you. As I have created the fiddle demo, can you please explain how to reproduce your problem in reference to that demo ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Seems like alert(ui.panel.selector) is not working in the DEMO.

Comment: I have created a demo http://jsfiddle.net/newair/Lxy5A/. when tabs clicked u get #ui-id-3 and #ui-id-5. In my scenario when I go back and come to the same page it displays as some increased number like #ui-id-7 for which it displayed #ui-id-3 previously.